# ¿Cómo instalo con pip un paquete de una rama específica?

Tags: python, git, pip

Estoy trabajando con dos proyectos a la vez en Python. Uno, digámosle `pr1` será un paquete que utilizaré en el otro.

Por ello, en mi fichero requirements.txt tengo esta línea:

```
git+ssh://git@gitlab.xx.com/mi_grupo/pr1.git
```

Sin embargo, pr1 acaba de "nacer", está en constante evolución y lo desarrollo en otra rama `feature-anyadir_cosillas`. Por ello, la rama master no tiene el `setup.py` para instalar el paquete y cuando hago `pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.xx.com/mi_grupo/pr1.git` se queja por ello.

Ahora bien, en la rama `feature-anyadir_cosillas` sí tengo dicho fichero `setup.py`, por lo que querría instalar con `pip` apuntando allí.

¿Cómo hago pues para bajarme un paquete en una rama en concreto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes utilizar `@rama` después de la ruta del repositorio git:

```
git+ssh://git@gitlab.xx.com/mi_grupo/pr1.git@feature_anyadir_cosillas
```

Puedes probarlo ejecutando el comando:

```
pip install git+ssh://git@gitlab.xx.com/mi_grupo/pr1.git@feature_anyadir_cosillas
```